# Get Geolocation Adress from coordinates in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

In `android` I can easily get `onLocationChanged` to work and gets the mobile latitude and longitude.

However once I got these coordinates How can I get the address of the mobile e.g

```
XYWZ Road, GRDSASDF Sector 823432, Australia  etc
```

Comment: you want address of perticular latitide longitude ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Geocoder** is a class for handling **Geocoding** and **Reverse Geocoding**.

1. *Geocoding* is the process of transforming a street address or other
   description of a location into a (latitude, longitude) coordinate.
2. *Reverse Geocoding* is the process of transforming a (latitude,
   longitude) coordinate into a (partial) address.

The amount of detail in a reverse geocoded location description may vary, for example one might contain the full street address of the closest building, while another might contain only a city name and postal code. The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the `isPresent()` method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists.

The `getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)` method returns an array of Addresses that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude. The returned addresses will be localized for the locale provided to this class's constructor.

The returned values may be obtained by means of a network lookup. The results are a best guess and are not guaranteed to be meaningful or correct. It may be useful to call this method from a thread separate from your primary UI thread.

[Here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/get-address-from-location-using.html) a Tutorial to get familiar with the Geocoder:

```
public class AndroidFromLocation extends Activity {

double LATITUDE = 37.42233;
double LONGITUDE = -122.083;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       TextView myLatitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylatitude);
       TextView myLongitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mylongitude);
       TextView myAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myaddress);

       myLatitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(LATITUDE));
       myLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(LONGITUDE));

       Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

       try {
  List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

  if(addresses != null) {
   Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
   StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
   for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
   }
   myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
  }
  else{
   myAddress.setText("No Address returned!");
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  myAddress.setText("Canont get Address!");
 }

   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class from Android.

By using the method

```
List<Address>    getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GeoCoder Method.

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) 
    System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you find out the lat long, which you said you have already done.

Then, you can use the following code to get the complete address in a list. Here is the code:

```
// this will fetch the data of current address  
                    List<Address> addresses=geoCoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10);

                    int i=1;
                    for(Address addObj:addresses)
                    {
                        // this will make the loop run for 1 time 
                        if(i==1)
                        {
                            //variables to split address line
                            String add_line1_extract;
                            //setting street address
                            streetaddressText.setText(addObj.getAddressLine(0));
                            //splitting city and state
                            add_line1_extract=addObj.getAddressLine(1);
                            String string = add_line1_extract;
                            String[] parts = string.split(",");
                            //Setting city
                            part1 = parts[0]; 
                            cityText.setText(part1);
                            //setting state
                            String part2 = parts[1]; 
                            stateText.setText(part2);
                            //setting country
                            countryText.setText(addObj.getAddressLine(2));

                            i++;

                            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class LocationSpeecher extends MapActivity{
MapController mc;
       MapView myMapView;
       MapController mapController;
       GeoPoint point;
       MyPositionOverlay positionOverlay;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_speecher);

         MapView myMapView=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.myMapView);           
            mapController=myMapView.getController();   


           myMapView.displayZoomControls(true);        
           mapController.setZoom(17);



          // myMapView.setSatellite(true);

           myMapView.setStreetView(true);
           myMapView.setTraffic(true);              



            LocationManager locationManager; 
            String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE; 
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context); 

            Criteria crta = new Criteria(); 
            crta.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); 
            crta.setAltitudeRequired(false); 
            crta.setBearingRequired(false); 
            crta.setCostAllowed(true); 
            crta.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(crta, true); 

         // String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER; 
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 
            updateWithNewLocation(location); 

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener); 
            } 
        private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() 
        { 

        @Override 
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        updateWithNewLocation(location); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { 
        updateWithNewLocation(null); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { 
        } 

        }; 

        private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) { 
            String latLong;
            TextView myLocation; 
            myLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myLocation); 

            String addressString = "no address found"; 

            if(location!=null) {            



                Double geoLat=location.getLatitude()*1E6;
                Double geoLng=location.getLongitude()*1E6;
                GeoPoint point=new GeoPoint(geoLat.intValue(),geoLng.intValue());

                mapController.animateTo(point);

            double lat = location.getLatitude(); 
            double lon = location.getLongitude(); 
            latLong = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lon;           

            double lattitude = location.getLatitude(); 
            double longitude = location.getLongitude(); 

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault()); 
            try { 
            List<Address> addresses= gc.getFromLocation(lattitude, longitude, 1); 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            if(addresses.size()>0) { 
            Address address=addresses.get(0);
            for(int i=0;i<address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();i++)
                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n"); 
            sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n"); 
        sb.append(address.getCountryName()); 
        } 
            addressString = sb.toString(); 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { 
            } 
            } else { 
            latLong = " NO Location Found "; 
            } 

            myLocation.setText("Current Position is :\n"+ latLong + "\n"+  addressString ); 

}
```